# How can I make wlan0 show up automatically when I plug in my WiFi USB adapter?

Tags: linux, wifi, embedded, wlan

Before I plug in the USB there is no wlan0:

```
root@beaglebone:/mnt/etc/network# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

root@beaglebone:/mnt/etc/network# ifup wlan0
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2
Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Cannot find device "wlan0"
Bind socket to interface: No such device
Failed to bring up wlan0.
root@beaglebone:/mnt/etc/network# iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

root@beaglebone:/mnt/etc/network#
```

I need to reboot, then:

```
BeagleBoard.org BeagleBone Debian Image 2014-04-23

Support/FAQ: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian
Last login: Wed Apr 23 20:23:53 2014 from 192.168.7.1
root@beaglebone:~# iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

root@beaglebone:~#
```

fyi, my `/etc/network/interfaces` file looks like:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#allow-hotplug eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
# Example to keep MAC address between reboots
#hwaddress ether DE:AD:BE:EF:CA:FE

# The secondary network interface
#allow-hotplug eth1
#iface eth1 inet dhcp

# WiFi Example
allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid "andromeda"
    wpa-psk  "happypeoples"

# Ethernet/RNDIS gadget (g_ether)
# ... or on host side, usbnet and random hwaddr
# Note on some boards, usb0 is automaticly setup with an init script
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.7.0
    gateway 192.168.7.1
```

Comment: Try dmesg | grep firmware to see if that's all set, there shouldn't be errors there. There's a firmware-misc-nonfree* deb you may need.  The allow-hotplug wlan0 should be in there for removable devices (like USB), it enables something when you plug it in.